# self.fetchedResultsController is throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS while _fetchedResultsController working just fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**my.h:**

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
//Managed Object Context of CoreData. Passed from AppDelegate

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
//FetchedResultsController for managing fetched objects from coreData.
```

**my.m:**

```
- (NSNumber *) customMethod
{

    NSError *error;
    if ([[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) 
    {
      return @1;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    return @0;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{

    if (self.fetchedResultsController != nil)  //Here it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2)
      //If used _fetchedResultsController, works fine
    {
        return self.fetchedResultsController;
    }

    //custom code to create FetchResultController.

   return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

According to my knowledge, difference between self.var & _var is:

- self.var is an accessor reference that invokes getter & setter.
- _var is a direct accessor reference which skips invoking getter & setter.

I am unable to find a clue of my problem from this justification. Can anybody put some light on the scenario here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom method declares to return void, but you are returning a pointer to an NSNumber. This object will be deallocated when your method returns, and the pointer will be invalid.

Self. fetchedResultsController becomes  [self fetchedResultsController]. So you are recursively calling this method. In your accessor you should access _fetchedResultsController instance variable, not call the method by using dot syntax.

You should do this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)  //Here it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2)
      //If used _fetchedResultsController, works fine
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    //custom code to create FetchResultController.

   return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

By the way, if this is till unclear to you, it might turn out to be a very daunting task to use Core Data, although it is very courageous of you :) .

Comment: NO, By mistake I wrote it here. Check the question.

Comment: Your second point is the answer though. same name for property & method. Thanx. It was a silly mistake & I was making it a big issue. Thank you.. :)

Comment: Great. The important point is to never access ivars outside getters, setters, dealloc, and init methods unless you have a very good reason. The reason is that calling the accessor methods in the accessors themselves can get recursive, and when calling accessors in init and dealloc method, you are calling methods on object that is not yet fully initialised, or being destroyed, respectively. Also, those are not the times that you want to be triggering KVO notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use _fetchedResultsController in the nil check as well as in the return within non nil . otherwise you repeatedly call the method you defined and not the property!

Make sure you understand how setters and getters get generated by properties.

Answer (score 1):

I find this is a very instructive error. Basically,

```
 - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {}
```

is the  getter for the fetchedResultsController property. And

```
if(self.fetchedResultsController) {}
```

is a test to see if fetchedResultsController has been set (!= nil). This is normally the way we test to see if a property is set. We ask the getter if it's not nil. However, the problem is we're attempting to do this inside the fetchedResultsController's getter! So, we are asking the getter if it is set and it runs the method our request is sitting in. It runs the getter and again reaches the test which asks the getter whether the fetchedResultsController property has been set. This cycle would go on indefinitely, but the compiler is kind and helps us by crashing after looping for a while. It's no use asking the accessor whether the fetchedResultsController has been set, not from within the getter. Since if the variable was set it would have set its backing instance variable, we ask for that instead. 
[image]

Normally we should not access ivars directly. This is one exception. Initializations are another exception. The reason being that we shouldn't refer to self if self does not yet exist. Anyhow, I found it instructive.